# Create a dynamic Custom View in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-custom-view

I need to generate a dynamic custom view in my application.

I need a custom view that is formed by an image button and 2 text views, above and bellow the button. There should also be an onClick listener on the image button, that will call a function when pressed.

By dynamic I mean those views will be created on demand, there should be a "dummy" structure from which I should be able to create as many custom views as I need.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just create the layout for your view with an xml and then use the layout inflater:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View yourView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_layout, parent, false);
```

To access it's components then you use:

```
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) yourView.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a custom view class MyCustomView that extends the View class. Create a separate XML layout (the dummy structure) for the custom view and inflate it into the custom view constructor,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_view_layout, this, true);
```

You can add any listeners to the Button views that will make part of this compound view class. Take a look at this link for further understanding: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

At the end, just treat this object as just a view and you place it on the interface wherever you want.